# How can I remove an Online Account?

Tags: 16.10, online-accounts

Is it possible to remove accounts shown in the screen below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting an account to see what options appear?

Comment: So it doesn't look like Google is actually signed in. Do you not want to see the options at all?

Comment: So, I need to sign in first in order to remove them?

Comment: They're not actually signed in. They're there for you to click them and sign in. Why do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: Because I don't need them. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open a terminal and check which account plugin packages are installed :

`dpkg --get-selections | grep account-plugin`

- When you want to remove the Unity Flickr account plugin execute :

`sudo apt purge account-plugin-flickr libaccount-plugin-flickr`

- When you want to remove the Unity Google account plugin execute :

`sudo apt purge account-plugin-google libaccount-plugin-google`

**Update addressing the requested information in the comment below**

In earlier editions of Ubuntu (14.04/16.04) the `libaccount-plugin` packages don't exist, so

- to remove the Flickr account plugin execute : `sudo apt purge account-plugin-flickr`
- to remove the Google account plugin execute : `sudo apt purge account-plugin-google`

Comment: In 14.04 and 16.04 I get E: Unable to locate package libaccount-plugin-flickr
It works under 16.10 Do you have a solution for other supported versions?

Comment: @ElderGeek in 16.04 the package is `account-plugin-flickr`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Gnome DE and don't use Online accounts at all you can remove the package itself with `sudo apt-get remove gnome-online-accounts` if you want to remove the entire package along with any configuration data you can use the command `sudo apt-get purge gnome-online-accounts`

Source:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/gnome-online-accounts?action=remove

Comment: Some clarification ... as shown in the screenshots, @orschiro uses the Unity desktop environment, so the account plugins are plugins for the Unity Control Center. The package gnome-online-accounts comes pre-installed only, when you are using the GNOME desktop environment, so when you want to remove it, you have to install it manually before. And when you install this package, the whole GNOME Control Center is getting installed alongside, means you will find two control centers in the Ubuntu Unity system settings. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thanks for the clarification. Corrections made.

Comment: I noticed that, Too bad I can only upvote it once.... ;-)